# PHP bug in array_column()?

Tags: php, function

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5342,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5623,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    )
);
$first_names = array_column($records, 'first_name', 'last_name');
var_dump($first_names);
```

PHP outputs such result as:

```
array(2) { ["Doe"]=> string(5) "Peter" [0]=> string(4) "Jane" }
```

But where is **John Doe**? Why i can see only 3 names?

Comment: You can't have an array with duplicate keys!

Comment: Ty. it was my mistake(((

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, the third parameter to [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) is the key to use as the index.  In your data, both `Peter` and `John` have the same value for `last_name` (the index key).

This means the result array *would be*:

```
array(
    "Doe" => "John",
    "Doe" => "Peter",
    0 => "Jane"
)
```

**but** arrays cannot have duplicate keys – in this case `Doe` – so only one of the values is kept.